# Validar campo nombre que no este vacio con jquery

Tags: jquery

Estoy usando Jquery para validar el campo de nombre soy nuevo y quiero aprender pero basado en mi logica me dice que deberia ser asi sin embargo no me esta funcionando el codigo.

```
if ($("#nombre").value==("")){
            alert("Introduzca su nombre");
          }
```

Comment: `if ($("#nombre").val()==""){`

Answer (score 1):

Saludos puedes realizado así:

```js
function validar(){
 //obtengo el valor del input 
  //y elimino espacios al inicio y final del mismo
 var nombre = $.trim($("#nombre").val());
  //verifico si tiene un valor 
 if(nombre == '' || nombre == null){
   $("#nombre").val(null);
   alert('Ingrese el nombre.');
    return false;
  }
}//end function validar
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
<button onclick="validar();">Validar</button>
```

Si te fijas también he usado el **$.trim** que permite eliminar los espacios al inicio y al final del valor.

dentro de la condicion valido mediante un **if** si el valor obtenido es vacio o es null y muestro una alerta, a su vez limpi el input dando el valor de **null**.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Links:

[$.trim](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/)

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que es:

```
if ($("#nombre").val == ""){
            alert("Introduzca su nombre");
          }
else {}
```

Answer (score 0):

El método es [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
if ($("#nombre").val().trim() == ""){
    alert("Introduzca su nombre");
} else {}
```